# Deploying Grizzly app to AWS via Boxfuse fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, grizzly, cloudcaptain

I have a Grizzly application that I'm trying to deploy to AWS using Boxfuse. The Grizzly server is started like so:

```
String instanceIP = System.getProperty(BOXFUSE_INSTANCE_IP)
String port = System.getProperty(BOXFUSE_PORTS_HTTP)
String BASE_URI = "http://" + instanceIP + ":" + port;
System.out.println(BASE_URI);
final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("com.homer.web");
GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);
```

This all works fine locally (I see my 'Hello World' page if I go to http://localhost:8080) but when I push to AWS I get this Grizzly error:

```
i-620cd2df => http://52.58.25.146:8080
i-620cd2df => Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Failed to start Grizzly HTTP server: Cannot assign requested address
i-620cd2df =>   at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.java:299)
i-620cd2df =>   at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.java:119)
i-620cd2df =>   at com.homer.web.MyApp.main(MyApp.java:43)
i-620cd2df => Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
i-620cd2df =>   at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
i-620cd2df =>   at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
i-620cd2df =>   at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
i-620cd2df =>   at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
i-620cd2df =>   at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
i-620cd2df =>   at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bindToChannelAndAddress(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:131)
i-620cd2df =>   at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bind(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:88)
i-620cd2df =>   at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:248)
i-620cd2df =>   at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:228)
i-620cd2df =>   at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:219)
i-620cd2df =>   at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener.start(NetworkListener.java:714)
i-620cd2df =>   at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer.start(HttpServer.java:278)
i-620cd2df =>   at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.java:296)
```

I don't know if I'm supposed to do anything differently for the AWS version but I thought the point was I wouldn't have to. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On AWS for single-instance applications `BOXFUSE_INSTANCE_IP` contains the Elastic IP of the application for that environment. On instance bootup it still belongs to the old version of the application (if any) and only gets assigned to that instance once the healthcheck has passed.

Comment: Thanks Axel that worked. Additionally, you suggested just using the default IP (0.0.0.0) and port (80) and that worked best.